# jquery .animate scrollTop function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn animated scrolling with jQuery on a portfolio website. I think this should work in theory but my buttons still just 'jumps' to its `href` instead of scrolling.

The javascript is enclosed in the `$(document).ready(function() {})` thing:

```js
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  if (target.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#skills">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">My Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Me</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm hoping that this would scroll to my section with those ids instead of jumping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use preventDefault() to stop default ahref action first and it should be fine

```
// added e parameter to click callback
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function(e) {
  // use prevent default function
  e.preventDefault()
  var target = $(this.hash);
  if (target.length) {    
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 1000);
  }       
});`
```

You are activating default action of the `<a>` tag so browser have no time to animate scroll because you are there already.

Comment: the default href action is indeed stopped now, but now, nothing happens.

Comment: Because rest of the function is not working, the example above mine shows how to do it properly. You should change your `this.hash` to `$(this).attr('href')`

Comment: Actually, the function would have worked originally. I just found out I was using the slim version of Jquery and it didn't have the .animate effect. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try following.

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    if (target.length) {    
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 1000);
    }       
});
```